# Collapsible toolbar in Angular app with PrimeNG

Tags: css, angular, toolbar, responsive, primeng

I want to use PrimeNG in a new Angular app. The app needs a toolbar on the top of the screen that collapses his items on small devices.

PrimeNG implements the [toolbar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/toolbar) but I can't figure out how to make it collapsable, just like the one in the [PrimeNG web page](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/).

Desired behaviour :

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have to add the below css class with the tag `<i class="fa fa-bars"></i>` but this is not a toolbar it's a collapsable side menu.

Comment: Imagine that the fa-bars icon includes the links 'Get started', 'Themes' and 'Support' buttons (when the icon appears on small devices the links disappear). How can I do that?